# C# El nombre '' no existe en el contexto actual // es método, que no es válida en el contexto indicado

Tags: c#

como va? Soy nuevo en todo esto y estoy aprendiendo siguiendo tutoriales e instructivos por la web.

Tuve que hacer un programa práctico que pude resolver de una manera, pero no pude resolverlo de la forma en que yo quería, usando una clase que contuviera otra.

El problema es el siguiente, tengo una clase "Caja" con la propiedad Estado, la cual inicializo con el constructor en 0. Luego tengo otra Clase que se llama "AtencionCajas" que tiene un objeto de la clase "Caja" creado con el constructor.

En un Windows form, tengo un botón que al clickearlo me debería mostrar el estado de la caja en un label ( me mostraría 0).

Puse 3 label para intentarlo de 3 maneras, la fácil(label1 en el código), era creando directamente en el código del click del botón un objeto de la clase caja, y luego pasándolo al label. Ese quedó OK.

Pero yo quiero crear el objeto de la clase 'Caja' desde un objeto de la clase 'AtencionCajas", y es lo que no estoy pudiendo.

En el label2 trato de mostrar la propiedad del objeto caja creado a través de la clase atencioncajas pero me sale:

> El nombre 'caja2' no existe en el contexto actual WindowsFormsApp3
>   C:\Users\Guardia\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp3\WindowsFormsApp3\Form1.cs
>   26 Activo

En el label3 traté de ver si creando un método dentro de 'AtencionCajas' que me devolviera el valor de la propiedad podía hacerlo, pero tampoco, ahí me sale:

> 'AtencionCajas.EstadoCaja2()' es método, que no es válida en el
>   contexto indicado WindowsFormsApp3
>   C:\Users\Guardia\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp3\WindowsFormsApp3\Form1.cs
>   27 Activo

Dejo el código en el link de abajo (la clase Caja tiene otros métodos que no los estoy usando todavía, porque quería usarlos de la misma manera que el problema que estoy planteando con la propiedad 'Estado', y no entiendo que me falta o por que me están saliendo esos errores).

Este es mi código:

```
Caja.cs:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
class Caja
{
    class Nodo
    {
        public int info;
        public Nodo sig;
    }
    private Nodo raiz,fondo;
    private int estado;
    public int Estado
    {
        set
        {
            estado = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return estado;
        }
    }
    public Caja()
    {
        raiz = null;
        fondo = null;
        estado = 0;
    }
    public bool Libre()
    {
        if (estado == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    public bool Vacia()
    {
        if (raiz == null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    public void Insertar(int info)
    {
        Nodo nuevo = new Nodo();
        nuevo.info = info;
        nuevo.sig = null;
        if(Vacia())
        {
            fondo = nuevo;
            raiz = nuevo;
        }
        else
        { 
            fondo.sig = nuevo;
            fondo = nuevo;
        }
    }
    public int Extraer()
    {
        if (!Vacia())
        {
            int informacion = raiz.info;
            if (raiz == fondo)
            {
                raiz = null;
                fondo = null;
            }
            else
            {
                raiz = raiz.sig;
            }
            return informacion;
        }
        else
            return int.MaxValue;
    }

}
}

AtencionCajas.cs:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
class AtencionCajas
{
    private Caja caja2;
    public AtencionCajas()
    {
        caja2 = new Caja();
    }
    public int EstadoCaja2()
    {
        return caja2.Estado;
    }


}
}

Form1.cs*:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Caja caja1 = new Caja();
        AtencionCajas at1 = new AtencionCajas();
        label1.Text = caja1.Estado.ToString();
        label2.Text = caja2.Estado.ToString();
        label3.Text = at1.EstadoCaja2.ToString();
    }
}
}
```

Espero haber sido lo mas claro posible!! Si hace falta que agregue algo mas         avisen!! Muchisimas gracias desde ya!!

Comment: Hola. El codigo debe estar incluido en la pregunta. Solo el codigo que reproduce tu error. Mira [ask] si tenes alguna duda. Esta bastante bien explicado el problema, solo falta que anexes el codigo.

Comment: Gracias por responder, el código lo puse en el siguiente link: http://collabedit.com/n2a85

me falto aclarar que era el código.

El label3 ya lo resolvi, me faltaba el parentisis al final del método. Me queda sin resolver el label 2!

Comment: No. El codigo relevante a la pregunta no puede ir en un enlace externo, ya que estos se pierden y la pregunta deja de tener sentido. El sitio esta ideado para que tu pregunta pueda ayudarle a futuros usuarios, y sin el codigo, la pregunta no tiene sentido. Deja solo el codigo correspondiente. Usa el boton [edit] y muestra tu problema en la pregunta.

Comment: Entendido gbianchi. Gracias por agregarlo como corresponde, lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que solucionar varias cosas en tu código para hacer que funcione. Ya que estás comenzando voy a intentar ser lo más claro posible.

1º Error del label 2 da el siguiente error:

> El nombre 'caja2' no existe en el contexto actual WindowsFormsApp3
>   C:\Users\Guardia\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp3\WindowsFormsApp3\Form1.cs
>   26 Activo

Este error lo que nos indica es que no existe el objeto caja2 y es cierto, en ningún momento lo creamos con lo cual no lo podemos utilizar.

El objeto caja2 al que intentas acceder es una propiedad del objeto AtencionCaja con lo cual, para acceder a caja2 tienes que hacerlo a través de at1 que es tu objeto AtencionCaja, con lo cual quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
label2.Text = at1.caja2.Estado.ToString();
```

Como se he dicho, se puede ver que para accedder a caja2 lo hacemos a través de at1.

Si sólo haces este cambio, te va a dar otro error que es el siguiente:

> AtencionCajas.caja2' no es accesible debido a su nivel de protección
>   (CS0122) -

¿Qué significa este error? Que al declarar el objeto Caja dentro de AtencionCaja como privado, no podemos acceder a él desde otra clase. Para solucionarlo podemos declararlo como public(que es lo que he hecho yo) o crear un método get para podoer acceder a él, con lo cual la clase AtencionCaja tendría declarado el atributo caja de la siguiente manera:

```
public Caja caja2;
```

2º Error del label 3 da el siguiente error:

> AtencionCajas.EstadoCaja2()' es método, que no es válida en el
>   contexto indicado WindowsFormsApp3
>   C:\Users\Guardia\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp3\WindowsFormsApp3\Form1.cs
>   27 Activo

Este error salta cuando hacemos

```
label3.Text = at1.EstadoCaja2.ToString();
```

¿porqué? Si te fijas, dentro de AtencionCaja no tenemos ninguna propiedad que sea EstadoCaja2, tenemos un **método** que se llama EstadoCaja2, con lo cual, para poder llamarlo, nos hace falta poner los paréntesis. Quedaría así:

```
label3.Text = at1.EstadoCaja2().ToString();
```

Al final tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
Caja.cs:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
class Caja
{
class Nodo
{
    public int info;
    public Nodo sig;
}
private Nodo raiz,fondo;
private int estado;
public int Estado
{
    set
    {
        estado = value;
    }
    get
    {
        return estado;
    }
}
public Caja()
{
    raiz = null;
    fondo = null;
    estado = 0;
}
public bool Libre()
{
    if (estado == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
public bool Vacia()
{
    if (raiz == null)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
public void Insertar(int info)
{
    Nodo nuevo = new Nodo();
    nuevo.info = info;
    nuevo.sig = null;
    if(Vacia())
    {
        fondo = nuevo;
        raiz = nuevo;
    }
    else
    { 
        fondo.sig = nuevo;
        fondo = nuevo;
    }
}
public int Extraer()
{
    if (!Vacia())
    {
        int informacion = raiz.info;
        if (raiz == fondo)
        {
            raiz = null;
            fondo = null;
        }
        else
        {
            raiz = raiz.sig;
        }
        return informacion;
    }
    else
        return int.MaxValue;
}

}
}

AtencionCajas.cs:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
class AtencionCajas
{
public Caja caja2;
public AtencionCajas()
{
    caja2 = new Caja();
}
public int EstadoCaja2()
{
    return caja2.Estado;
}


}
}

Form1.cs*:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Caja caja1 = new Caja();
    AtencionCajas at1 = new AtencionCajas();
    label1.Text = caja1.Estado.ToString();
    label2.Text = at1.caja2.Estado.ToString();
    label3.Text = at1.EstadoCaja2().ToString();
}
}
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Pablo!! Fuiste muy claro, y lo entendí muy bien!!!

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido, he intentado ser lo más claro posible. Si te ha valido como respuesta, márcala como tal ya que así me ayudarás a mi y a los usuarios que tengan las mismas dudas que tú. Ánimo con la programación.